# Surface Geometry

Tags: geometry

I am having some troubles understanding some concepts in surface geometry. For example things like: a regular curve, unit speed, curvature, signed curvature.

Can anyone recommend some works with a more graphical and intuitive approach to this type of work?

Would really appreciate it!

Comment: It seems like a very general question. Can you tell us something about your background ?

Answer (score 0):

The book called Exploring Curvature by James Casey, Vieweg, 1996, has lots of diagrams and has lots of interesting approaches to understanding the difficult notion of curvature. However, it may not be that easy to get your hands on a copy. At the time this book was written Casey was in the Mechanical Engineering Department of the University of California at Berkeley.